# Quelle serait une variante plus soutenue de « péter la balloune de quelqu’un » ou « éclater la bulle de quelqu’un » ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

> Sincèrement, je te prie de m’excuser d’avoir pété ta balloune, c’est vrai que tu ressembles plus à la photo que j’ai prise de toi que celle que tu as prise toi-même, même s’il t’est difficile de te faire à cette idée.

> Sincèrement, je te prie de m’excuser d’avoir éclaté ta bulle, c’est vrai que tu ressembles plus à la photo que j’ai prise de toi que celle que tu as prise toi-même, même s’il t’est difficile de te faire à cette idée.

Comment: Comme ça a l'air d'être du français Québécois je ne peux pas vraiment m'avancer sur quelle expression serait plus soutenue, mais je tiens juste à signaler que normalement, on ne dit pas "je m'excuse", mais "excusez moi/excuse moi" ou "je vous prie de m'excuser"

Comment: @Lyzvaleska Je m'excuse par avance mais tant qu'à être prescriptiviste, on n'écrit pas *français Québécois* mais *français québécois* (adjectif) et on n'écrit pas non plus *excusez moi/excuse moi* mais *excusez-moi/excuse-moi* :-)

Comment: C'est la traduction de: to burst your bubble. détruire les illusions

Comment: http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=s%27excuser&id=3810. On le dit. LBU14,781b5.

Comment: briser les rêves de quelqu’un
dissiper les illusions de quelqu’un https://www.noslangues-ourlanguages.gc.ca/fr/cles-de-la-redaction/balloune

Comment: @Lambie Pertinent, merci Lambie!

Comment: *Baloun, qué anglicisme ? Es prouvençau !* [Marsiho, capitalo franceso de l'empèri … dóu baloun !](https://www.departement13.fr/marsihocapitalofrancesodelemperidoubaloun/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Sincèrement désolé d'avoir douché tes espoirs, mais il faut bien reconnaître que la photo que j'ai prise de toi est plus fidèle que ton autoportrait, aussi difficile que ce soit pour toi de l'admettre.*